# Modificar sentencias que ejecuta TFDTable de FireDAC

Tags: sql-server, oracle, delphi

Me encuentro trabajando en Delphi XE7, con conexión a SQL Server y Oracle. Con base a mi experiencia queriendo utilizar `soDescNullLast` y `soNullFirst` (propiedades de `TFDSortOptions`) y darme cuenta de que `TFDTable` ignora por completo estas propiedades y deja que el *DBMS* ordene los valores `null` a su manera, al realizar un `first` o `last` obtuve resultados distintos, y lo que necesito es obtener los mismos resultados tanto en SQL Server como en Oracle.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Existe alguna propiedad o manera de modificar las sentencias `SELECT` que genera `TFDTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para responder directamente a tu pregunta:

**No es posible** modificar directamente la sentencia `select` que genera el `TFDTable`

La solución a tu problema es cambiar de componente. El `TFDQuery` es, en muchos aspectos, igual que el `TFDTable`. La diferencia principal es que eres tu quien escribe la sentencia `select` que se lanza a la base de datos.

No es la única diferencia, pero en el uso básico, podría decirse que *casi* lo es.

De hecho, las propiedades son en su mayoría las mismas, al igual que los eventos, lo que te permite sustituir uno por otro muy fácilmente.

Si tu *query* tira de una sola tabla, el componente de manera similar al `TFDTable` genera automáticamente las sentencias de inserción, actualización y borrado, dejándote siempre el chance de manejarlas tu mismo.

He preparado la siguiente imagen poniendo lado a lado una toma del inspector de objetos de un `TFDTable` y un `TFDQuery` (con Delphi 10.3)

[image: Inspector de objetos lado a lado]

Para utilizar `TFDQuery` tal como si fuese un `TFDTable`, edita la propiedad `SQL` y coloca el texto

```
select * from MiTabla
```